# OpenIPMI on setup connection returns RMCP error

Tags: ipmi

I'm using OpenIMPI library for managing Shelf Manager (Pigeon Point ShMM-500)
After creatinf domain and verifying all connection arguments setup_done_handler returns an error

```
33554450
```

I'm using OpenIPMI macroses for decoding error. This error is RMCP+ error, and real error code is

```
18
```

That error occures after sending **RMCP+ Open Session Request** and getting **RMCP+ Open Session Response**

This error occures not permanent and the multiple rebooting of Shelf Manager can solve this problem, but sometimes I need 10 or 15 reboots before I will be succesfully connected to ShMM.

Does somebody know, what that error means?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that current error is a IPMI_RMCPP_ILLEGAL_PARAMETER. But what it really means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection can be established only by proper using of connection method.

Early, I used a method

```
ipmi_args_setup_con();
```

with specific setup args.
Now I'm using the concreate method

```
ipmi_ip_setup_con();
```

And it works all time.

Hope, that it will be helpfully for someone.